# How to map key ~ to `?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint, I set a hot key that <kbd>`</kbd> will open a new terminal window. But now I found that when writing markdown, I need this key. How could I map <kbd>~</kbd> to <kbd>`</kbd>?

Comment: ~ is your home directory, I'm not sure you'd want to remove this particular key. Use modifiers for that, for instance I use ctrl-alt-t to open a new terminal window. That's the very purpose of modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map keys using xbindkeys :

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
# write default configuration
xbindkeys --defaults > /home/jylam/.xbindkeysrc
```

You can then edit ~/.xbindkeysrc to add you own bindings, or install xbindkeys-config as well to use the graphical editor.

I strongly suggest NOT to use ~ as a shortcut, as it represents your home directory (~/). Use modifiers, like ctrl or alt.

Comment: I try to use xbindkeys-config to do the config, but I don't know how to write the action "enter ` for me"?

Comment: You can know the name of a key using 'xbindkeys -k' ; "enter" is Mod2 + Return here, for instance.

Comment: I want to bind ctrl + grave key  to enter the grave key, how to write the .xbindkeysrc?

Answer (score 1):

I use an application called Guake for this. Instead of opening up a terminal window, it has a persistent drop-down terminal that appears when you press the hotkey. By default it is set to F12, but it can be changed to other keys. When I first started using it, I set it to `, but found that didn't work very well, because, as Ravachol said, you use that key for other things.